# Unable to run Docker image with 'docker-compose up'

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

I've been trying to start up a development environment for a Docker image that I've found on GitHub, but I've had a great deal of trouble with it. Whenever I run `docker-compose up`, I'm faced with the following error:

```
assets_1    | /bin/sh: 1: run-p: not found
assets_1    | error Command failed with exit code 127.
assets_1    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I then install run-p with the command `npm install run-p`, but this leads me to the exact same error, and I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I'm unsure if this issue resides in this specific Docker image that I've downloaded from GitHub, but the owner seems to have gotten everything working fairly simply on his end.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sql-language-server",
  "displayName": "SQL Language Server",
  "description": "SQL Language Server Extension for VSC",
  "version": "0.12.0",
  "main": "./packages/client/out/extension",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/joe-re/sql-language-server.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sql",
    "language-server",
    "language-server-protocol",
    "lint",
    "autocompletion"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/joe-re/sql-language-server"
  },
  "author": "joe-re <joe.tialtngo@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "publisher": "joe-re",
  "scripts": {
    "vsc-compile": "npm run vsc-compile:client && npm run vsc-compile:server",
    "vsc-compile:client": "cd ./packages/client && yarn run compile",
    "vsc-compile:server": "cd ./packages/server && yarn run prepare-vsc-extension",
    "watch": "run-p watch:client watch:server",
    "watch:client": "cd ./packages/client && yarn run watch",
    "watch:sqlint": "cd ./packages/sqlint && yarn run watch",
    "watch:server": "wait-on ./packages/sqlint/dist/src/index.js && cd ./packages/server && yarn run watch:index",
    "watch:dev-server:client": "cd ./example/monaco_editor && yarn run webpack:watch",
    "watch:dev-server:server": "wait-on ./packages/server/dist/src/index.js && cd ./example/monaco_editor && yarn run start",
    "dev": "run-p watch:sqlint watch:server watch:dev-server:client watch:dev-server:server",
    "vscode:prepublish": "yarn run vsc-compile"
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.45.1"
  },
  "activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:sql"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.switchDatabaseConnection",
        "title": "Switch database connection",
        "category": "SQLLanguageServer"
      },
      {
        "command": "extension.fixAllFixableProblems",
        "title": "Fix all auto-fixable problems",
        "category": "SQLLanguageServer"
      },
      {
        "command": "extension.rebuildSqlite3",
        "title": "Rebuild SQLite3 Client",
        "category": "SQLLanguageServer"
      }
    ],
    "configuration": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "sql-language-server configuration",
      "properties": {
        "sqlLanguageServer.connections": {
          "scope": "resource",
          "type": "array",
          "default": [],
          "description": "connection setting"
        },
        "sqlLanguageServer.lint": {
          "scope": "resource",
          "type": "object",
          "default": {},
          "description": "lint setting"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*",
    "example/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "wait-on": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0",
    "run-p": "0.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Here is `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  assets:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/sql-language-server:rw
    command: 'yarn dev' # 'tail -f /dev/null'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
      POSTGRES_USER: sqlls
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sqlls
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql_db
      MYSQL_USER: sqlls
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: sqlls
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  postgres:
  mysql:
```

And here is the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12

COPY ./package.json yarn.lock /opt/sql-language-server/
COPY ./packages/server/package.json /opt/sql-language-server/packages/server/
COPY ./packages/sql-parser/package.json /opt/sql-language-server/packages/sql-parser/
COPY ./packages/sqlint/package.json /opt/sql-language-server/packages/sqlint/
COPY ./example/monaco_editor/package.json /opt/sql-language-server/example/monaco_editor/
COPY ./example/monaco_editor/.sqllsrc.personal.json /root/.config/sql-language-server/.sqllsrc.json
WORKDIR /opt/sql-language-server
RUN yarn
```